# Is the homology of the based loop space of a compact globally symmetric space a polynomial ring?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, loop-spaces, symmetric-spaces

Let $X$ be a space. Then the homology group $H_*(\Omega X;\mathbb{Q})$ of the based loop space of $X$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra with the Pontryagin product given by loop concatenation.

When $X=G$ is a compact simply-connected Lie group, we know that $H_*(\Omega G;\mathbb{Q})$ is a polynomial algebra concentrated in even degrees. (In fact, I don't have any reference for this fact. I guess it is proved by showing that the loop concatenation and the group structure of $G$ give rise to a Hopf algebra structure, and then using the classification. Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Now my question is how about when $X=G/H$ is a compact globally symmetric space: Is $H_*(\Omega X;\mathbb{Q})$ also a polynomial algebra?

Remark: I ask this question because it seems to me that when talking about loop spaces, compact Lie groups and symmetric spaces (where the first is a special case of the second) should be treated in a unified way. For example, if we are only interested in $H_*(\Omega X;\mathbb{Q})$ as vector space, then by the work of R. Bott and later W. Ziller, we know a basis such that the degree of each of the vectors is completely determined by the (restricted) root datum associated to the symmetric space $X$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not. For an explicit counterexample we can take $X = \mathbb{CP}^2$. The main technical result we'll use to do the computation is the following, which is Theorem 16.13 in Felix, Halperin, and Thomas' *Rational Homotopy Theory*.

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be simply connected such that $H_{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{Q})$ has finite type (finite-dimensional in each degree). Then $H_{\bullet}(\Omega X, \mathbb{Q})$ is the universal enveloping algebra (in the graded sense) of the (graded) Lie algebra $\pi_{\bullet}(\Omega X, \mathbb{Q})$ given by the rational homotopy groups of $X$ (shifted by one degree) with the [Whitehead bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_product).

The rational homotopy groups of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ can be determined as follows. We know that it's simply connected, and the Hurewicz theorem gives $\pi_2(\mathbb{CP}^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. The long exact sequence in homotopy applied to the fiber sequence $S^1 \to S^5 \to \mathbb{CP}^2$ gives that its higher homotopy groups are the same as those of $S^5$; rationally this is a $\mathbb{Q}$ in degree $5$ and nothing else, so overall we get that the rational homotopy of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ in degrees $2$ and $5$, and nothing else. Taking loop spaces we get that the rational homotopy of $\Omega \mathbb{CP}^2$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ in degrees $1$ and $4$, and nothing else; in particular all Whitehead brackets vanish.

It follows that $H_{\bullet}(\Omega \mathbb{CP}^2, \mathbb{Q})$ is the free graded-commutative algebra on generators $\alpha, \beta$ in degrees $1$ and $4$. This algebra is not a polynomial algebra, because graded-commutativity (equivalently, the vanishing of the Whitehead bracket $[\alpha, \alpha] = 2 \alpha^2$) forces $\alpha^2 = 0$, so this algebra has nilpotents.

Comment: What's special about the case that $X$ is a Lie group is that 1) all Whitehead brackets vanish (true more generally if $X$ is an $H$-space) and 2) all the generators of rational homotopy are in odd degree, so after taking loop spaces they end up in even degree. Then the above theorem gives your result as a special case.